# how to display lightmaps in the appcreator

Tags: archilogic, 3d.io

running on macbook iOs X(yosemite) and chrome browser,

i try to view an archilogic model:

[Model Used](https://spaces.archilogic.com/model/archilogic/be0pxujd?modelResourceId=2be87bcc-4e67-48b8-9c96-cec588cbcad7&mode=edit&view-menu=camera-bookmarks&main-menu=save&logo=false)

in https://appcreator.3d.io/

but the result doesn't seem to display the same lightmaps mapping on interiors:

https://app.3d.io/lLOkYR

Comment: Can you give an example on how that's not the same lightmap? I'm seeing the same results in both URLs (but admittedly the lighting setup in A-Frame seems different)

Comment: thanks for getting back @geekonaut. guess it's my computer then. see comparing screen capture, left window is 3d.io right is spaces. https://gfycat.com/gifs/detail/WeightyJaggedElver

Comment: Noo, sorry . I didn't read this one right, I think.

I saw the lightmap for outside but in the living room, I'm also not seeing it. Great question!

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to the fact that the lighting system in spaces editor is a different one than the lighting system in aframe. I recommend you to adjust the lighting in your aframe scene using the following parameters (search for these values inside your html code in the app creator):

`lightMapIntensity: 1.887; lightMapExposure: 0.55`

also you can adjust overall lighting intensity by modifying:

`<a-scene io3d-lighting="intensity:0.9">`